# SQL Replication Monitor does NOT show publication properties - Transactional Replication

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, ssms, availability-groups

The setup I have is as follows:

a) Version SQL Server 2014 SP1 CU6.
b) publication is on a
   separate    availability group [AG1] and subscriber is part of
   another AG [AG2].
c) Distribution is on a separate host.
d) subscriber is pointing to    listener of AG2 [AG2LN]
e) publication is repointing to listener of    [AG1LN]

**Scenario:**

I have failed-over publication AG to secondary node and the subscriber AG to its secondary node.

**Problem :**
 On the publication host [ AG1 - secondary node - current primary],  Using SSMS replication monitor, I am trying to see the properties of the publication.  I am getting the below error message:

**Error message:**

> SQL Server Cannot retrieve  the information for publication xxx  on host [ AG1 primary node]

Please can someone let me know if this is a limitation of SSMS and if there is a workaround available.

Comment: Does this fix itself after a day (or a longer-ish time like 3 hours) in the new state or does it continue to stay like this after multiple days without a failover?